Crash on androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView tryGetViewHolderForPositionByDeadline
I have a chat application, i can see on crashlytics, a crash i can't reproduce i tried a lot of correction but no one works here is the trace of crash :
Fatal Exception: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException
Inconsistency detected. Invalid item position 13(offset:13).state:20 androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView{427b4ed VFED..... ........ 0,0-1440,2381 #7f0900bd app:id/chatMessages}, adapter:xxxx.xxxx.android.adapters.ChatMessageAdapter@8f1e0eb, layout:xxxx.xxxx.android.customView.NpaGridLayoutManager@2d7bf10, context:.android.activities.chat.ChatWindow@931912b
androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.tryGetViewHolderForPositionByDeadline (RecyclerView.java:6821)
I  use NpaGridLayoutManager
        public class NpaGridLayoutManager extends LinearLayoutManager {
public NpaGridLayoutManager(Context context) {
    super(context);
}

/**
 * Disable predictive animations. There is a bug in RecyclerView which causes views that
 * are being reloaded to pull invalid ViewHolders from the internal recycler stack if the
 * adapter size has decreased since the ViewHolder was recycled.
 */
@Override
public boolean supportsPredictiveItemAnimations() {
    return false;
}

@Override
public void onLayoutChildren(RecyclerView.Recycler recycler, RecyclerView.State state) {
    try {
        super.onLayoutChildren(recycler, state);
    } catch (IndexOutOfBoundsException e) {
        ErrorHandlerUtils.onErrorFirebaseLog("Error onLayoutChildren "+e.toString(), "", null, MyApplication.getInstance().getUserId(), MyApplication.getInstance().getAccessToken());
    }
}

I initialize recyclerView like this
linearLayoutManager = new NpaGridLayoutManager(this);
linearLayoutManager.setStackFromEnd(true);
recyclerView.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);

…..
recyclerView.swapAdapter(adapter, true);

When I do some remove add to data :
data.remove(data.size()-1);
I notifyDataSetChanged like that
  void notifyDataSetChanged(){
  this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        recyclerView.stopScroll();
        recyclerView.getRecycledViewPool().clear();
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
       }
   });

My version recycleView :
    implementation 'androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.3.2'

Why i'm still getting this error ? Any help will be appreciated
